# MatlabGUI How to create Buttons dynamically and recognize that the Button was pushed

Tags: matlab, user-interface, dynamic, callback

I am working on a GUI to control a Oscilloscope. Due to the problem that not all Oscilloscopes have the same number of channels I have to create some buttons dynamically. I can create the buttons but I don't know how to recognize that the button was clicked.

I have to do the same thing with some textinputfields.

At the moment, I can create the buttons dynamically, but don't know how to get the data.

```
classdef GUIcontrol < handle
    properties
        figure
        button = {};
    end   
    methods 
        function obj = GUIcontrol()
          %create figure for 'GUIcontrol'
           obj.figure=figure
           position=[20 20 80 20];
          for n= 1:4
              obj.button{n}=createButton(obj, position);
              position(1)=position(1)+120;
          end


        end

        function button= createButton(handle, position)

          %create a pushbutton UI

          button = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',....
                             'string', 'unknownYet',...
                             'units', 'pixels',...
                             'Position',position,...
                             'callback', @eg_fun);  
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You already assigned a callback (`'callback', @eg_fun`) to the button, so every time the button will be clicked the function `@eg_fun` will be executed. From inside this function you can decide to read the content of any other text box, provided you know its handle.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot☺️